# Store locations for a iPhone App using jQuery Mobile & Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have built a iPhone app using jQuery mobile and Phonegap 2.0.7.

I am using the Google Maps Javascript API V3 with my API code to display the map.

**What I'm trying to do:**

- User selects which type of store they want to find (example Starbucks Stores or KFC Stores).
- Display the google map (**implemented**)
- Get the users location if they accept (**implemented**)
- Link to somewhere (JSON? KML?) of the store listing and display the pins on the map.

Basically I want to be able to add/change stores in the future in a file or somewhere on my google account and it update the locations to all apps already installed.

I also want to be able in the future have some basic information on each pin. example store hours.

I've tried KML layer seems to work but google caches it so when I update it it wont work, KML seems to be a bit old?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use Apigee. It's quick and free ;) 
here is a video about the codeing and usage of the remote server: https://blog.apigee.com/detail/build_a_store_locator_app_with_html5_phonegap_an_api_based_backend_webcast_recording

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please summarise the link in your answer; that way, if the link goes stale the answer won't be completely useless.